# Glitch in monthly leaderboard

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I noticed an interesting glitch (feature?) while looking at the monthly reputation league:
[image: Congrats to Safdar for breaking the leaderboard :)]

Notice that the month reputation is greater than the total reputation, which should not be happening (unless said user started off with -11 rep, which is impossible). There are two possible explanations I could think of for this behaviour:

1. Total reputation tracks downvotes while monthly reputation does not do so.
2. The summations are incorrect, and this is indeed a bug.

Could mods/devs clarify what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, you aren't the only person shocked. I was too..

TBH, this began after I started playing around with deleting an answer and testing the delay in the rep recalculation taking place. I did it for a pretty long time. Checked the rep tables and I saw this. Checked multiple posts on Meta, both here and mother meta, nothing found.

After seeing this, I incidentally clicked onto the [one post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation) that talked about this. It is pretty common, makes me wonder, why I couldn't find it at all.

But, there is the answer. It doesn't count the fact that I deleted an answer that had one upvote and downvoted answers and so screwed up the rep calculation completely since they were a *private reputation event*. The answer had 4 downvotes, so the gain was +2, and then 9 downvotes on answers makes it 11